# mySQL SHOW COLUMNS Extra field

Tags: mysql

The MySQL documentation states

> The Extra field contains any additional information that is available about a given column. The value is auto_increment for columns that have the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute and empty otherwise.

As far as I have been able to find thus far the Extra field does not appear to take any other valid values.  Is this correct?

Comment: is it coming when you insert a data in db

Comment: This is not a question of anything 'coming' in any way.  I was just wondering - does the Extra field have any other legit use in MySQL, other than noting that the column in question is an AUTO_INCREMENT column?